# Error in function buscar in BST

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I have a problem with a BST (Binary Search Tree) or ABB in Spanish.

My problem is that the function `search()`, or `buscar()` in Spanish in the code below, doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```html
#TAD de Árbol Binario de Búsqueda
class ABB(object):
 def __init__(self, data):
     self.right = None 
  self.left = None 
  self.data = data 

 def insert(self, data):
  if self.data: 
   if data < self.data: 
    if self.left == None: 
     self.left = ABB(data) 
    else: 
     self.left.insert(data) 
   elif data > self.data: 
    if self.right == None: 
     self.right = ABB(data) 
    else: 
     self.right.insert(data) 
  else: 
   self.data = data 

 def buscar(self, x):
  while x != self.data and self.data != None:
   if self.data < x:
    self.left.buscar(x)
   else:
    self.right.buscar(x)
  if self.data == x:
   return True
  if self.data == None:
   return False

n = ABB(8)
n.insert(3)
n.insert(10)
n.insert(1)
n.insert(6)
n.insert(4)
n.insert(7)
n.insert(14)
n.insert(13)
print("existe?",n.buscar(22))
```

It is supposed to return true or false if the searched number exists or not. And in both cases that does not happen. The error message is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'buscar'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in `buscar`, see embedded comments:

```
def buscar(self, x):
    if x != self.data:
        if self.data > x: # you should check > x not < x
            if self.left:  # check if the child-node exists before calling recursively
                return self.left.buscar(x)
            else:
                return False
        else:
            if self.right:  # same for right child
                return self.right.buscar(x)
            else:
                return False
    if self.data == x:
        return True
```